# Would INSERT statement in one transaction block a DELETE statement in another transaction?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, isolation-level

Considering the following schedule of two concurrent transactions T1 & T2;

T1

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1, 'Ben', 6);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2, 'Anne', 4);
```

T2

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (3, 'Amy', 3);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2, 'John', 4);
DELETE FROM employee WHERE name LIKE 'A%'; **// line a**
```

T1

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE name LIKE 'J%';
Commit;
```

T2

```
Commit;
```

Would `"line a"` get blocked in any `isolation level` as it tries to modify a row which has been modified by `T1`?
So, would these two `transactions` lead to a `Dead Lock` for any isolation level?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no other structures on the table (ex. triggers) and the storage engine is innoDB, it will not lead toward Dead Lock.

The `Dead Lock` will not really depend on the isolation level, since the isolation level is related to the read operations, while the Dead Lock is related to the write operations.

Here, since the inserts are still not committed to the table, they will not be affected by the other session.

It's worth to note that if the transactions are in isolation level `Serializable`, one of the transactions will fail (in your example T2) since the data was modified after the read lock from T1 was obtained, but it will not generate a `Dead Lock`.

However, things will change if there are triggers or other structures that might cause competition for existing storage elements (rows, index pages, gaps, etc.) in the database and cause the Dead Lock, not because of the `INSERT` or of the isolation level, but because of the additional logic involved.

Same is true for many other DB systems such as PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc. however there could be DB systems that have implementations that can lead toward Dead Lock for this scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please tell me which records would be there in the employee table after executing T1 & T2 in the above order to preserve the Repeatable Read isolation level?

Comment: Assuming the table is empty to start with, each session will remove it's own inserts only (where applicable).